# Differential Equations problem with variable substitution difficulties

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need some help with this (seemingly) simple problem. As before, it comes from Apostol "Calculus", Volume 1, Section 8.28, Question 23 and it states:

Solve the differential equation $(1+y^2e^{2x})y^{'} + y = 0$ by introducing a change of variable of the form $y = ue^{mx}$, where $m$ is constant and $u$ is a new unknown function.

This seems to be straight forward but I seem to be having problems. My working so far has been as follows:

$$
y = ue^{mx} \Rightarrow y^{'} = u(me^{mx}) + u^{'}e^{mx} = e^{mx}(u^{'}+mu)
$$
so we obtain:
$$
(1+(ue^{mx})^{2}e^{2x})e^{mx}(u^{'}+mu) + ue^{mx}= 0
$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$
(1+u^{2}e^{2(m+1)x})e^{mx}(u^{'}+mu) + ue^{mx}= 0
$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$
e^{mx}((1+u^{2}e^{2(m+1)x})(u^{'}+mu) + u) = 0
$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$
(1+u^{2}e^{2(m+1)x})(u^{'}+mu) + u = 0
$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$
u^{'}+mu = \frac{-u}{1+u^{2}e^{2(m+1)x}}
$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$
u^{'} = \frac{-u}{1+u^{2}e^{2(m+1)x}} - mu
$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$
u^{'} = \frac{-u - mu(1+u^{2}e^{2(m+1)x})}{1+u^{2}e^{2(m+1)x}}
$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$
u^{'} = \frac{-u - mu - mu^{3}e^{2(m+1)x}}{1+u^{2}e^{2(m+1)x}}
$$
And I seem to get somewhat stuck as to how to proceed with this.  Im trying to convert this (somehow) into a differential equation that has separate variable to allow for extracting a solution but the trick seems to be eluding me. If anyone has any suggestions that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Invert your fourth-last step. See if you can keep u on one side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. up to  $(1+u^2e^{2(m+1)x})(u'+mu)+u=0$

Then, why not chosing a value of $m$ in order to simplify thr equation ? Obviously $m=-1$ is a good choice :
$$(1+u^2)(u'-u)+u=0$$
$$\frac{1+u^2}{u^3}u'=1$$
$$\frac{-1}{2u^2}+\ln|u|=x+c$$
The result expressed on the forme of the inverse function $x(u)$ can be inverted thanks to the Lambert W function :
$$u=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{W(e^{-2(x+c)})}}$$
$$y=ue^{-x}=\pm \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{W(e^{-2(x+c)})}}$$

Comment: Sorry, have only just got back this to you after several days away for Xmas. GIven the above hints and suggestions, I have worked through to a solution. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: We can choose $m$ freely. Let $m=-1$.

Comment: I had the same idea. You post it first while I was typing my anwer. Cheers.